# Components are rendering again and again after i set mouse move event listener for body in react js

Tags: reactjs

I wrote a event listener for body to get the mouse position in react js

```
getMousePosition = (event) => {
        if(this.props.navActiveClass === "active-sm"){
            var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
            this.setState({
                mouseX:event.pageX,
                mouseY:event.pageY,
            })
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', this.getMousePosition);
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        document.body.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.getMousePosition);
    }
```

after that whenever i move the mouse showing component is re-rendering again and again.

Comment: its because you are doing `setState` in `getMousePosition` method, `setState` trigger re-rending of the component.

Comment: If you are not using `mouseX` or `mouseY` in your rendering, and you definitely don't want it to re-render, you could check if just `mouseX` and `mouseY` updated in [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate).

Answer (score 4):

As @Mayank said, you are using setState with an on mousemove. this.setState({}) causes the component to rerender. You should keep those two values out of state.

You can put them into the constructor like this

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.mouseX = 0;
    this.mouseY = 0;
}
```

and then in your function you set them the same way, just without setState.

```
getMousePosition = (event) => {
        if(this.props.navActiveClass === "active-sm"){
            var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

            this.mouseX = event.pageX;
            this.mouseY = event.pageY;
        }
    }
```